# error in creating series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error when creating a series in pandas.
Whenever I try to print the series I have created, I get an error.

The code I am running:

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = [1,2,3,4]
index = ['a','b','c','d']
s = pd.Series(data2, index)
print(s.shape)
s
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    s
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 611, in displayhook
    text = repr(value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 80, in __repr__
    return str(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 59, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1060, in __unicode__
    width, height = get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\terminal.py", line 33, in get_terminal_size
    return shutil.get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
    size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate this error in my IDE - I don't think this is a pandas problem.

Comment: I am using pycharm and I am not able to recreate it with python-3.6, which python version you are using .?

Comment: i am usingpython 3.4.4

Comment: @Neha : I tried with console, getting results without any errors.

Comment: @avinashse: why i am getting this error and how can i correct it.

Comment: @Neha please try running from python cli once, if you are hitting same error.

Comment: @avinashse i m not getting the error when i m running the code from cmd

Comment: Thanks avinashse

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to `pyshell`, not to pandas. 
Try to run it through `python` directly or `jupyter console`, because the code you provided is correct.

Comment: As u r saying error is related to pyshell  so there is no way out to correct it

Comment: My guess is that pandas is unable to determine the size of your terminal because it's pyshell. Try to run your code through another shell to determine if pyshell is the root cause of this error.

Comment: yes the pyshell is the root cause. Thank u so much.